# regex match getting wrong in group 1

Tags: java, regex, matching, regex-group

I have a string and I need this pattern `$body.anyname` or `$body.anyname.anyname` or like this, but not like `$body.anyname.`
I wrote this regex `\$[body](\w+((\[\d\]){0,}\.\w+(\[\d\]){0,}){0,})` its matching the whole string but I need the `body.anyname` in group 1, but getting `ody.anyname` This can be done by string manipulation but for some reason I need to use regex. Check the regex here https://regex101.com/r/PigNVO/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use and assertion for a whitespace boundary at the right to exclude the dot.

Note that this part `[body]` is character class that  matches either `b` `o` `d` or `y` and is not part of the first group.

```
\$(body(?:\.\w+)+)(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `\$` Match `$`
- `(` Capture group 1
- `body` Match literally

  - `(?:\.\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching a dot and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWrWiT/1)

Comment: If you want your pattern with the repeated digits between square brackets and 2 capturing groups `\$(body\.\w+)((?:(?:\[\d\])*\.\w+(?:\[\d\])*)*)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/kwcYf8/1